# How to calculate a charge of capacitors on a circuit (both paraller and serial)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

I have a circuit with capacitors on it:

[image: circuit figure 1]

I am trying to figure out the charge on each capacitor.

The following is given:

[image: given]

i know that parallel capacitors follow the equation

[image: paraller]

and that capacitors in series behave according to this equation:
[image: series]

I dont know how to use that knowledge to find out the charge of the capacitors.
I also dont know how to apply this to find the voltage across all the capacitors and the total voltage.

This is from a homework question but i want to find out the general concepts of calculating voltages and charges on any circuits.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just apply Kirchoff's Loop Law and conservation of charge.

Comment: pretty funny that this question was closed considering that it just earned me a famous question tag. Pretty sure it is useful to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two capacitors are in series the charge on them must be the same. This is because there is no source or sink for charge in between the two capacitors:

[image: Capacitors]

That means $Q_1 = Q_2$. You know $Q_2$ so you now know $Q_1$ and you can calculate the voltages $V_1$ and $V_2$ and the total voltage across both, $V_{12}$.

Because $C_3$ is parallel with $C_1 + C_2$ you know $V_3 = V_1 + V_2$ and from this you can calculate $Q_3$. Finally, if you calculate the combined capacitance of $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ and you know the voltage across this combined capacitor $V_{123}$ you can calculate a combined charge $Q_{123}$, and because $C_4$ in series $Q_4 = Q_{123}$.